# Restarting Android application after process is killed

Tags: android, android-activity

When my application is idle, Android kills the process.
If user reopens the application after some time, only the top Activity is created - this is a problem for me because the activity depends on initialization of other objects (which are now destroyed).

What I want to do in that case is to re-launch the application.
How can I do that?

Comment: Android kills a App to free memory. So if the app is idle, it is likely to be killed after sometime when the OS needs memory to execute other programs.

Comment: Maybe you need a service on the background to keep your _vital_ _objects_ running. You can use a `Sticky Intent` to make sure the service is restarted when it is killed.

Answer (score 9):

Just identify that your `Application` is being launched after it was previously destroyed by Android, you could do this by keeping a variable in a custom `Application` class, and set it to `true` after your applicaiton is initialized. So when the applicaction is re-launched, this flag is false, and then just make an `Intent` to launch your main `Activity` specifying `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` :

```
Intent reLaunchMain=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
reLaunchMain.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(reLaunchMain);
```

Comment: where should i put this code? It crashes if i do it in onCreate of the activity

Comment: what exception do you get? you should be calling this when you now that your application is re-launched by Android.

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu hi, is the Application object recreated when the activity you were on (and get recreated) is not the launcher? I got to ask this because I can't hook up the debugger at the time when activity is recreated.
Tks

Answer (score 1):

I think this answer only for you.

After finish progress call this

```
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, sameactivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should probably be looking at storing such Objects in your app's implementation of the [`Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class.

If these objects contain state that needs to be more persistent, you should save the state of such Objects in each Activity's `onPause()` method, either to the database, in SharedPreferences or remotely.

Comment: even if you keep them in the `Application` class, after the process is killed by `Android` the objects will be lost, and your will not start with the "initialization activity", but with the last visible one.